# laravel - php variable into css file

Tags: php, css, laravel

I have a question to You. Is it possible in **Laravel** to pass variable from **MySQL** to the **CSS**? I mean:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-aqua" 
     style="width: 20%" 
     role="progressbar" 
     aria-valuenow="20" 
     aria-valuemin="0" 
     aria valuemax="100">
```

And i want to have width from database and `aria-value-now` from database too.

Comment: yes. you can do it with javascript. Get the value from the database. Pass it via controller and then use javascript to append it.

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your style in your HTML and not in a seperate scss/css file, you can use variables like you normally do in blade files.

```
style="width: {{$width}}%"
```

When the view gets rendered it just replaces the variables with it's values. This means the HTML will just see a normal percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using inline CSS it is much easier to use values from Database.

```
//Controller

$cssValue = ValueModel::all();
return view('yourBlade', ['css' => $cssValue]);

//Blade Template

<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-aqua" style="width: {{ $css->witdh_column }}" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ $css->area_value }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria valuemax="100">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, and the blade templating engine makes it so simple.

example code.

Controller

```
public function test()
{

$style_values = Css::select('width', 'aria_value_now')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();

return view('sample.view', compact('style_values'));

}
```

and in your view.blade.php

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-aqua" style="width: {{ $style_values->width}}%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ $style_values->aria_value_now }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria valuemax="100">
```